# How can I add an icon to document.createElement()?

Tags: javascript, firebase, svelte

I can display an icon in React but I haven't figured out how to display it in svelte. I get everything from my database except the icon, it throws an error...

> Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document':

```
function getAllPosts(doc) {

    const dataList = document.querySelector('#content');

    let div = document.createElement('div');
    let title = document.createElement('h1');
    let body = document.createElement('span');
    let uid = document.createElement('h6');
    let timestamp = document.createElement('span');
    let comments = document.createElement('p');
    let likes = document.createElement(Icon);

    let createComment = document.createElement('textarea');
    let btn = document.createElement('button');

    createComment.style.cssText = 'border-radius:10px;border:1px  solid #ddd;-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px  #000;';
    btn.style.cssText = 'border-radius:10px;border:1px  solid #ddd;-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px  #000;';



    div.setAttribute('class', 'post');
    title.textContent = doc.data().title;
    body.textContent = doc.data().body;
    uid.textContent = doc.data().uid;
    timestamp.textContent = doc.data().timestamp;
    likes.textContent = doc.data().likes;
    comments.textContent = doc.data().comments;
    btn.innerHTML = "Add Comment"; 

    div.appendChild(title);
    div.appendChild(body);
    div.appendChild(uid);
    div.appendChild(timestamp);
    div.appendChild(likes);
    div.appendChild(comments);
    div.appendChild(createComment);
    div.appendChild(btn);
    
    dataList.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: That (Icon) you are trying to create is not an html element...create an ("img") element or ("i") element and then append your icon to that.

Comment: This is vanilla js but not svelte.